# JENKINS: After jenkins version updation, job is not starting

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using docker to run my Jenkins instance.

The version which we are using was 2.121. Since last Saturday after the container restart, all my pipeline got vanished. After several hit and trial, when I updgraded to version 1.121.1. All my job got visible again. But when I tried to run any jobs. It is not getting started, after clicking on the build button nothing is happening.

What should I do? any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You can try to `reload configuration from disk` button in the jenkins global configuration menu, if you didn't moved the jobs store path (`${jenkins_home}/jobs`) it should reload all jobs configs, btw check logs once jenkins is starting if its not complaining about anything related

Comment: YESSSS... nothing else worked, thanks - please enter this as an answer